# Check if two dictionaries having a DateTime key share the same Date

Tags: c#

I have two dictionaries. I am storing a value with a specified time. Now i want to be more granular while dealing with it. I wish to compare if both dictionary has the same month and the year,irrelevant of the days. How can i possibly do that.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try *Linq* to find the keys' intersection:

```
  Boolean hasSameKeys =
    (dict1.Keys.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1)).Intersect(
     dict2.Keys.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, 1)))).Any();
```

If you want to check if there's year and month in the dictionary, you can use Linq once again:

```
  int month = 3;   // <- Month of interest
  int year = 2014; // <- Year of interest
  Boolean hasKeys = dict1.Keys.Where(x => (x.Year == year) && (x.Month == month)).Any();
```

If you want to *aggregate* your data, e.g. *sum up* the values within *each month*:

```
  Dictionary<DateTime, int> oldDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>() {
    {new DateTime(1999, 1, 25), 1},
    {new DateTime(1999, 2, 25), 2}, // <- These values should be added up
    {new DateTime(1999, 2, 27), 3}, // <- These values should be added up
    {new DateTime(1999, 3, 25), 4},
    {new DateTime(1999, 4, 25), 5},
  };

  Dictionary<DateTime, int> aggregatedDict = 
    oldDict.GroupBy(pair => new DateTime(pair.Key.Year, pair.Key.Month, 1),
                    pair => pair.Value)
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                         x => x.Aggregate(0, (sum, item) => sum + item));
```

Comment: What if i wanna check if a certain month exists in the dictionary..irrespective of the day. If so update data. else add the date to the dictionary?

Comment: @user3305453: You can use Linq on dictionary keys, see my edit

Comment: i really require some bigger help here. I have Some data with some DateTime. Now i have to represent the data to the user by year,month,days and so on. So i have to pre-calculate all the values. Can you help me with this scenario.

Comment: @user3305453: if you want to aggregate your data you may use another Linq, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `DateTime` into a `String` keeping only the year and month in it:

```
String dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Then all you have to do is a simple string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I almost prefer to use linq. in this case Linq's `Any` method.

```
        var month = 3;
        var year = 2014;

        var dic1 = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
        var dic2 = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

        // fill dictionaries

        if (dic1.Any(date => date.Value.Year == year && date.Value.Month == month) &&
            dic2.Any(date => date.Value.Year == year && date.Value.Month == month))
        {
            // do something
        }
```